# Cucumber autotest cant find elements via Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, autotest

have problems with my java tests on Cucumber when i run them via jenkins on remote host.

My code:

step:

Given open link from property "bla-blalink"
And type to input with name "UserName" property: "login" on "LoginPage"

element:

```
@NameOfElement("UserName")
    @FindBy(id = "UserName")
    public SelenideElement username;

step def:

@And("^type to input with name \"([^\"]*)\" property: \"([^\"]*)\" on \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void typeToInputWithNamePropertyOn(String nameOfElement, String property, String page) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    sleep(5000);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(Constants.PROPERTY_PATH)) {
        properties.load(fileReader);
    }
    if ("LoginPage".equals(page)) {
        loginPage.get(nameOfElement).sendKeys(properties.getProperty(property));
    } else if ("MainPage".equals(page)) {
        mainPage.get(nameOfElement).sendKeys(properties.getProperty(property));
    } else if ("ActionPage".equals(page)) {
        actionPage.get(nameOfElement).sendKeys(properties.getProperty(property));
    }
}
```

configure:

```
@BeforeClass
    static public void setupTimeout() {

        /////////////////////////////////for remote runs////////////////////////////////
        //        Configuration.remote = "http://10.52.185.105:4419/wd/hub";
        //        Configuration.browser = "chrome";
        //        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        //        capabilities.setCapability(ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        //        WebDriver wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.52.185.105:4419/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        //        setWebDriver(wd);

        ///////////////////////////////////for local runs////////////////////////////
        Configuration.timeout = 10000;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        Configuration.browser = "chrome";
```

What i tried:
it works locally
it works on remote machine(without jenkins)
change window size - doesnt help
change sleep on 35000ms - doesnt help

our jenkins 
not started as a service, so i dont know how to allow to interact with elements

output:

### T E S T S

Running ru.open.runners.BusinessPortalTest
июн 13, 2018 9:55:27 AM com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer getWebDriver
INFO: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1 - let's create new webdriver
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 5610
Only local connections are allowed.
июн 13, 2018 9:55:31 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
июн 13, 2018 9:55:33 AM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory logBrowserVersion
INFO: BrowserName=chrome Version=67.0.3396.87 Platform=XP
июн 13, 2018 9:55:33 AM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory createWebDriver
INFO: Selenide v. 4.11.4
июн 13, 2018 9:55:33 AM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory logSeleniumInfo
INFO: Selenium WebDriver v. 3.12.0 build time: 2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z
июн 13, 2018 9:55:33 AM com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer createDriver
INFO: Create webdriver in current thread 1: ChromeDriver -> ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (9879008c2825cc8b84a452e24010d66d)

Failed scenarios:
businessportaltest.feature:440 # Scenario: Change phone number

## 157222(verify ONLY with payment order)

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
29 Steps (1 failed, 27 skipped, 1 passed)
0m18.951s

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: there is no such element with name Имя пользователя at page ru.open.pageobjects.businessportal.LoginPage
    at ru.open.pageobjects.AbstractPage.get(AbstractPage.java:27)
    at ru.open.steps.MyStepdefs.typeToInputWithNamePropertyOn(MyStepdefs.java:63)
    at ?.And type to input with name "Имя пользователя" property: "login" on "LoginPage"(businessportaltest.feature:443)

remote machine - windows server 2012R

Comment: Can u add the initialization code for the driver?

Comment: Configuration.timeout = 10000;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        Configuration.browser = "chrome";  - - only this

Comment: shoud i add something else? like                                                              WebDriver wd = etc

Comment: What are the chromeoptions u have added to the driver?

Comment: as i sad only his path, locally it works fine ;)

Comment: Can you add this to the webdriver initialization  and check. `ChromeOptions chop =  new ChromeOptions(); chop.addArguments("no-sandbox"); driver = new ChromeDriver(chop);`

Comment: businessportaltest.feature:440 # Scenario: Change phone number
1 Scenarios (1 failed)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: there is no such element with name Имя пользователя at page ru.open.pageobjects.businessportal.LoginPage
 at ru.open.pageobjects.AbstractPage.get(AbstractPage.java:27)